# what is Turbo sim unlocked iPhone ? how is differ with factory unlock and unlocked iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, iphone-5

what is Turbo sim unlocked iPhone ? how is differ with factory unlock and unlock iphone ? what are the disadvantages of turbo sim unlocked ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 4):

I am using a turbo sim to unlock my Sprint iphone 4S.  Basically our iPhones are locked to some particular carrier frequency (eg AT&T, Sprint, Verzion, e.t.c) so they will work only with that carrier.

So when you use a trubo sim, you put a small chip under your sim card and insert into your iPhone. It will hack the frequency settings and will let you use your iPhone with any sim card.

**Factory unlocking : 
 Is officially getting your phone unlocked from your carrier and the best to unlock your iPhone. You can just put any sim card and it will work without any problem.**

Trubo Sim: 
Pros:

- You can use it with any carrier with out officially unlocking your iPhone.

Cons:

- In order to do this you need to install some networking profiles on your iPhone, by using the software provided along with your  turbo sim card .
- If you reset your phone you need to do all the steps to get it working.

I didn't really see any problems by doing this.

Comment: When we update iOS is it works well as it is ?

Comment: Usually the turbo sim provider will provide new updated version of the software when a new iOS is released. It usally takes them a while to updated their software. So you have to check their website and when the new download is available , then you should update your software in iPhone.  Until then you have to keep waiting.

Comment: This process is the same as Jailbreaking?

Comment: @vhakti no this is different from jail breaking your device. You can use this turbo sim with out jail breaking your device.